# Why is only one rectangle being drawn when calling canvas.drawRect in android?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, draw, rect

I'm trying to draw a rectangle for every string in an ArrayList using a foreach loop but it seems to only be drawing the last rectangle.

I've looked at similar questions but they had issues such as bottom of rectangle being higher than the top and calling drawPaint - but I do neither of these.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> ideas = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set the icon
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    assert actionBar != null;
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.actionbarfull);

    //Use API in future to GET all ideas
    ideas.add("Idea 1");
    ideas.add("Idea 2");
    ideas.add("Idea 3");
    setContentView(new IdeaRectangle(this, ideas));
}
```

}

**IdeaRectangle.java**

```
public class IdeaRectangle extends View {

Rect rectangle = new Rect();
Paint mBlue = new Paint();
Paint textPaint = new Paint();
ArrayList<String> ideasToDraw = new ArrayList<>();
int gap = 50;
int sidegap = 30;
int right = 0;
int height = 250;
int top = 0;
int bottom = 0;
int counter = 0;

public IdeaRectangle(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public IdeaRectangle(Context context, ArrayList<String> ideas) {
    super(context);
    ideasToDraw = ideas;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Setting colour of rectangle and text
    mBlue.setARGB(255, 0, 183, 255);
    textPaint.setTextSize(50);
    textPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
    ArrayList<Rect> rectangles = drawIdea(canvas, ideasToDraw);

    for (Rect rectangle : rectangles) {
        // Draw rectangle
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle, mBlue);
        canvas.drawText("This is an idea. There were " + rectangles.size() + " rectangles.", rectangle.left, rectangle.centerY(), textPaint);
    }
}

private ArrayList<Rect> drawIdea(Canvas canvas, ArrayList<String> ideas) {

    ArrayList<Rect> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();
    right = canvas.getWidth() - sidegap;

    for (String idea : ideas) {
        // Setting location of rectangle
        top = gap + (counter * (gap + height));
        bottom = top + height;
        counter++;

        System.out.println(sidegap + "," + top + "," + right + "," + bottom);
        rectangle.set(sidegap, top, right, bottom);
        rectangles.add(rectangle);
    }
    return rectangles;
}
```

The console log which prints out the rectangle's dimensions prints this:

```
04-23 12:47:44.920 11005-11005/? I/System.out: 30,50,1050,300
04-23 12:47:44.920 11005-11005/? I/System.out: 30,350,1050,600
04-23 12:47:44.920 11005-11005/? I/System.out: 30,650,1050,900
```

Comment: `rectangles.add(rectangle);` you are adding the same rectangle in your loop

Comment: ahah! that worked thanks!

Comment: no prob, your welcome